# How do I set an IFTTT event to fire at specific week days at 7:40?

Tags: ifttt

The standard IFTTT applet for time only allows me to set events every quarter hour. How do I set an event to trigger at 7:40 on Tuesday and Thursday? Specifically activating a Philips Hue blinking.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a bit of a gnarly workaround if you have a Google Calendar account.

1. Create a new Calendar (e.g. "IFTTT Blink")
2. Create weekly repeating events for Tuesdays and Thursdays in that calendar
3. In IFTTT, use the "Any Event Starts" trigger for Google Calendar, and choose your IFTTT Blink calendar

In my experience the events trigger dead on time, but of course there's always a risk of a small delay - that's just in the nature of these things.

(This may also work with IFTTT's other calendar integrations, but I haven't tried them.)